# Python - list transformation

Tags: python, list

Does anyone knows what magic I have to use to change x list:

> x = [1,2,3,4,5,11]

into y list?

> y = ['01','02','03','04','05','11']

Thank you all in advance for helping me...

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension (Python 2.6+):

```
y = ["{0:0>2}".format(v) for v in x]
```

Or for Python prior to 2.6:

```
y = ["%02d" % v for v in x]
```

Or for Python 3.6+ using f-strings:

```
y = [f'{v:02}' for v in x]
```

Edit: Missed the fact that you wanted zero-padding...

Comment: Interesting, I haven't heard of this "{0:0>2}" syntax. Is it covered on any PEP or other document?

Comment: It's a new syntax that's (supposedly) meant to gradually replace % syntax.  It's actually very nice for some things, and I've made a point of using it in my code, but it still looks weird to me after so long using %.  More info here: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 23):

You want to use the built-in [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> y = map(str, x)
>>> y
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

**EDIT** You changed the requirements on me! To make it display leading zeros, you do this:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,11]
>>> y = ["%02d" % v for v in x]
>>> y
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '11']
```

Comment: that semi-colon is staring at me! stop it!

Comment: Whooops! Old habits die hard.

Comment: And if I'd like to add zero if the number is one digit and I want my numbers to be 2 digit each?

Answer (score 10):

I would use a list comprehension myself, but here is another solution using map for those interested...

```
map(lambda v: "%02d" %v, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y = ['%02d'%v for v in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> [str(v).rjust(2,'0') for v in x]
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '11']
```

[rjust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) as a method of string class, takes an integer argument(result length) and an optional padding character

Answer (score 0):

to get the 0's:

```
y = ['%02d' % i for i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to format strings would be to use the string's zfill() method:

```
y = [str(i).zfill(2) for i in x]
```

Another thing: you might be after padding based on the largest item in the list, so instead of just using 2, you could do:

```
pad_length = len(str(max(x)))
y = [str(i).zfill(pad_length) for i in x]
```